# Prevent swipe from triggering ng-click handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, swipe, angularjs-ng-click

I'm working on implementing an iOS-like swipe-to-delete gesture on HTML table rows.  For example, a leftwards swipe on `Site11` will turn it from a standard row:

[image: A standard HTML table]

into a delete-able row:

[image: A standard HTML table with a delete-able HTML row]

I have this functionality working with the `ng-swipe-left` directive.  However, I also have a `ng-click` directive on each row that navigates to a different view of the application.  Currently, both events are triggered when I perform a swipe on a row, *except* when the swipe ends on the "Site11" text itself, as opposed to anywhere else within the row.  For example, this gesture will trigger both the `ng-click` and the `ng-swipe-left` handlers:

[image]

but this gesture will only trigger the `ng-swipe-left` handler:

[image]

**How can I prevent the `ng-click` handler from being fired if a swipe is performed on the row, regardless of where the swipe ends?**

Here's the gist of my HTML structure that defines each row:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td ng-click="openDetailPane()"
      ng-swipe-left="$parent.swipeDeleteItemId = item.Id" 
      ng-swipe-right="$parent.swipeDeleteItemId = 'none'">
    <div list-item></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x" />
      <span>{{item.ChildCount}}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The delete button is defined inside the `list-item` directive; it is only visible if its ID matches the `swipeDeleteItemId` property on the controller:

```
<div class="list-item">
  <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
  <div ng-class="{true: 'is-visible', false: ''}[item.Id === swipeDeleteItemId]">
    <div class="delete-item-swipe-button" 
         ng-mousedown="$event.stopPropagation();" 
         ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">Delete</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I should mention that I've only tried this in the desktop versions of Chrome and IE11 - I'm assuming a click and drag from a mouse registers identically to a swipe on a mobile device.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also met this situation and I finally found a tricky way to do that.
The `$event.stopPropagation()` mentioned somewhere only works in ngClick. Even writing a custom swipe directive by `$swipe` with `event.stopPropagation()` cannot prevent ngClick... So...

`$swipe` service will trigger both 'touch' and 'mouse' events by default. So does ngSwipeLeft and ngSwipeRight directives.
So when you do the swipe, it will trigger events by the following order:

1. touchStart
2. touchMove
3. touchEnd
4. mouseDown
5. mouseUp
6. click

I tested by mouse drag not touch directly, but my app will run on a touch screen on PC, and the swipe on this touch screen is emulating mouse drag. So the event type of `$swipe` service 'end' event in my app is 'mouseup'.
Then you can use a flag to do something like this:

```
<div ng-swipe-left="swipeFunc(); swiping=true;" ng-click="swiping ? ( swiping = false ) : clickFunc();">
   ...
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-swipe-left="swipeFunc(); swiping=true;" ng-mouseup="clickFunc();" ng-click="swiping=false;">
  ...
</div>
```

with `clickFunc()` like following:

```
$scope.clickFunc = function() {
   if( $scope.swiping ) { return; }
   // do something
}
```

This works for me. I hope this is also useful for you.

Comment: Couldn't find the order of firing documented anywhere, thanks for your research, enjoy the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem right now as well, and indeed only on a desktop browser. I thought that `preventDefault()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()` would do the trick but no. However, I did find a solution for it though. Try this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('noSwipeClick', function () {
    return function(scope, elm) {
        var el = angular.element(elm);
        el.bind('click', function(e) {
          if(scope.swipe.swiping === true) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        });
    };
});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div class="list-item">
  <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
  <div ng-class="{true: 'is-visible', false: ''}[item.Id === swipeDeleteItemId]">
    <div no-swipe-click class="delete-item-swipe-button" 
     ng-mousedown="$event.stopPropagation();" 
     ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">Delete</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to assign `$scope.swipe.swiping = true` in your controller when actually swiping and setting it to false when done