# Angular (angular-touch) swipe left within another swipe left

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Im building an app using phonegap and [angular-touch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) . I have the menu closing using a swipe left, but I want this to apply to the divs within it too. But they also have `ng-click`. What seems to happen now is that the `ng-swipe-left` doesnt seem to work and the only way of closing the menu is by clicking an element thats listed in it.

Is it possible to have a situation where a blatant left swipe simply closes the menu and a blatant click clicks through to the item (which also closes the menu)?

```
<div class="side-menu" ng-class="{'show_menu' : show_menu }" ng-swipe-left="show_menu = !show_menu">
   <div ng-swipe-left="show_menu = !show_menu" ng-repeat="(f1,f2) in filters" >
         <div ng-click="$parent.show_menu = !$parent.show_menu;filterby(f1);$parent.show_add_edit = '';$parent.hide_listings = '';$parent.ShowHomeMenu = true;" ng-swipe-left="$parent.show_menu = !$parent.show_menu">{{f1}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found my answer  here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26678062/1652535 where there was a similar problem

Comment: Please close the question if you have already found the answer