# Performing a fast swipe causes button to not react to first click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, hammer.js

I am building an angular application, with a responsive navigation using the angular navbar. To let the navigation feel really smooth i use hammer to enable swiping right to show, and swiping left to hide the menu.

However, when the swiping to the right is performed fast (not super fast, but normal speed on a smartphone), the navigation buttons don't react to the first click on them, but only to the second.

If the swipe is executed slowly the buttons work as intended. If toggled by the menu toggle button it also works as intended.

Example gif (first slow, then fast):
[image]

This bug does NOT occure if you just resize the browser windows. Only if you use "toggle device toolbar" in chrome and select a device" and on my android 9 device with chrome for android.

the app.component.html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav fxLayout="column" mode="side" opened="false" class="hidelarge sidenav">
    <mat-nav-list fxLayout="column">
      <a href="#" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="navtext" [ngClass]="{'linkactive': router.url=='/home', 'link': true}"
        [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="navtext" [ngClass]="{'linkactive': router.url=='/maturanten', 'link': true}"
        [routerLink]="['/maturanten']">Maturanten</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="navtext" [ngClass]="{'linkactive': router.url=='/fotos', 'link': true}"
        [routerLink]="['/fotos']">Fotos</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="navtext" [ngClass]="{'linkactive': router.url=='/musik', 'link': true}"
        [routerLink]="['/musik']">Musik</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="navtext" [ngClass]="{'linkactive': router.url=='/raumaufteilung', 'link': true}"
        [routerLink]="['/raumaufteilung']">Raumaufteilung</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="navtext" [ngClass]="{'linkactive': router.url=='/ballordnung', 'link': true}"
        [routerLink]="['/ballordnung']">Ballordnung</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="navtext" [ngClass]="{'linkactive': router.url=='/kontakt', 'link': true}"
        [routerLink]="['/kontakt']">Kontakt</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill  (swiperight)="sidenav.open()" (swipeleft)="sidenav.close()" >
    <app-header (navToggle)="sidenav.toggle()">

    </app-header>
    <main class="minheight">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
    <app-footer>

    </app-footer>

  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

And in my app.module.ts:

```
...
export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = <any>{
    // override hammerjs default configuration
    'swipe': { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL },
    'pinch': { enable: false },
    'rotate': { enable: false },
    'pan': { enable: false },
    'tap': { enable: false },
    'press':{enable:false},
    'doubletap':{enable:false},
  };
}
...
providers: [
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: MyHammerConfig }
  ],
...
```

I importet hammer in my main.ts file like this:

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem. The solution might be also fitting for you.
If you swipe, this swipe performs also a click event forcing to focus the view on the right side.
If you click on 'Musik' in your example, the click is performing some sort of 'leave focus' from the right view to focuse the 'Musik'-button.
You could try preventing the click due to the swiping movement.
I know it's from AngularJs but it should work similiar.

```html
<div ng-swipe-left="swipeFunc(); swiping=true;" ng-click="swiping ? ( swiping = false ) : clickFunc();">
  ...
</div>
```

[See the this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26678062/12272930)
Let me know if that helped in your case.